# Database Design for spay/neuter clinic

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on setting up a database for a spay/neuter clinic. I think I got everything covered, but would like to get a second opinion in terms of my database. We are assuming having 100,000+ clients, each with multiple pets, and each pet with multiple work/invoices (they do more than just spay/neuter). To say the least my petdetails table is going to need to handle over 10,000,000 entries. If there is a better way to optimize my database for such an ever growing system, all suggestions are welcome. I am thinking of using MySQL for the database as we are looking to have a web based system and every hosting company has that.

I used an online database design tool to help build the system. It can be found going to the following: [Online Database Designer](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/)
Click save/load -> load (under server) -> input into field: spay/neuter

Here are my requirements:

- a 'client' does not necessarily have to have a 'user'. 'User' has to have a 'client'.
- 'Client' can have multiple 'notes'. 'Pets' can have multiple 'notes'.
- Clients can have multiple pets but each pet has a single client.
- An appointment can have multiple 'pets'. Appointments are only spay/neuter so only 1 'appt' per pet.
- Each appointment has a single date/location. There is no specific time.
- 'visit' is everything that happens to the pet in a given day (similar to orders in a store).
- 'services_rend' and 'goods' are applied to a pet. And all are loaded when a pet is selected (reason for the 'pet_id' value).
- multiple 'doctors' can work on a pet and a pet can change 'locations' in a day (thus why they are added to the 'goods' and 'services_rend'
- 'items' are individual items that can be applied to a pet . Items can be grouped with a series of 'sub_items'.
- 'schedule' is a listing of openings a client can book an 'appt'.
- verbage and codes are placed into their own tables in case they need to be changed later.

Comment: I like the designer site.   On your design, the Codes table is denormalized, and you may very well regret that choice when writing queries down the road.

Comment: I may end up splitting the codes table out. Mostly the codes table is used for a drop-down list for certain things. Just for now I didn't want to add 6 more tables with 4+ entries all with the same format (abbr - name)

Comment: Your design is well-thought and I like it. However, I have some questions. Why do you need a separate table for Schedule when it is one to one and there is not much field to consider unlike Location which I would understand because of its many associated fields and would violate the 3NF if there is no separate table. And what is the difference between your 'Note' in PetsDetail table against your Notes table?

Comment: And there's more. It looks you don't have a 'Doctors' or Veterinarian table although that's one of the field in your PetDetails table?

Comment: An appointement is for a single client. However a schedule_id can be applied to multiple appointments. Also a single location can be assigned to multiple days (aka schedule_ids, we have a mobile hospital), thus the need for the schedule table on its own. I have also renamed the PetsDetail table, so it makes more sense as that is a note for a specific service/item. I have gone ahead and broken up code, added more fields for some tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be essentially a simple veterinary patient relationship management application you're building, with appointment, services-rendered and billing functions.

Some review points on the schema:

- Almost everything is nullable.  Nullable fields should be the exception, not the rule.
- If `users`:`clients` are 1:1, fold them into one table.  The join is legitimate if a client can have no user, or if a client can have multiple users.
- I think what `petsday` represents would be called a visit, and what `petdetails` represents would be a service rendered in medical record terminology.
- `petsdayid` doesn't belong in `pet`.  If you want to be able to retrieve the "current" `petsday` for a given `pet`, look it up.
- Reverse the foreign key between `petsday` and `petdetails`: one visit may entail multiple services rendered, not the other way around.
- `petid` in `petdetails` is denormal once the above foreign key is reversed; remove it unless performance requires it.
- `codes` and `options` aren't linked to anything.  This may be understandable for `options`, but I'd suggest breaking `codes` up into multiple identically-structured tables with one for each set of codes: diagnosis, service, and so forth, so that foreign keys can be constructed that maintain code type-safety.
- You may want to split up `petdetails` into two tables, one for services (foreign keyed to service codes) and the other for goods (foreign keyed to items), with a subset of the fields common between them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and corrections. I have made quite a few changes based on your suggestions. Love the idea of splitting up services_rendered and items. I can have clients without user accounts, in fact a good chunk of clients may never even access our online system (making the username/password pointless for them).

Comment: I have adjusted the database even more, but not quite understanding the need to split up 'services_rend' and 'goods' into 2 separate tables. Every time I load the records, I will pull from both tables, which will require a join or two separate queries. Just wondering if this makes a difference in terms of performance, and if so, how.

Comment: Combine the two queries into one with `union all`.  This requires that both queries return the same columns in the same order, so you'll need to resolve the dissimilar columns; for example, a description column might come from the items table in the goods query and the service codes table in the services query, while some columns might be left null for rows where they're inapplicable.